# How can I prefix all links to static folder with CDN url?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm developing with `Nuxt.js`, and I have some static files inside the `static` directory. I want to serve them from a CDN, and from a separate domain to be cookie-free.

Is there a way in `webpack`, or `Nuxt.js` itself that can help me prefix all URLs pointing to the `static` directory with the CDN's URL in the built (and generated) files?

Comment: The [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045295/1206267) might be of some use hre.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm using this feature but it seems to be ineffective on paths to the `static` directory and they are still relative urls in the generated files.